# $n^3 \equiv n^5 \pmod{12} $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am proving that 
$$5n^3 + 7n^5 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$$
It would suffice to show 
$$n^3 \equiv n^5 \pmod{12}$$
How would I go about doing that?

I suppose I could just go through each $n \equiv r \pmod{12}$ with $r$ from $1$ to $11$ and show that $n^3 \equiv n^5 \pmod{12}$ for each, but that would be tedious.  Surely there's a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We need to show $$12|n^5-n^3$$ for each $n$.  Factor this as $$n^3(n-1)(n+1).$$ This quantity will always be divisible by 3 (why?) and will always be divisible by 4 (why?) so it is divisible by 12.

**Hint:** If I have three consecutive integers one is divisible by 3.

**Hint:** If $n$ is even then we are done.  If $n$ is odd both $n+1$ and $n-1$ are divisible by 2.

**Remark:** By this exact reasoning we actually get $24|n^5-n^3$ for each $n$.

Comment: Do you care to explain why $24 | n^5 - n^3$ for odd n?

Comment: For odd $n$, both $(n-1)$ and $(n+1)$ will be even, and one of them will be a multiple 4. Thus $(n-1)(n+1)$ is a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 2):

- $n^2 = 0,1,4$ or $9 \mod 12$ by checking each number $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ (we don't have to check $7,8,9,10$ and $11$ since they are negatives and $x^2 = (-x)^2).$
- $n^4 = (n^2)^2 = n^2 \mod 12$ by checking each number 0,1,4 and 9.
- thus $n^3 = n^5.$

Comment: Much quicker, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's just case $\rm\ p^j = 2^2,\ q^k = 3,\ d = e = 2\ $ of this simple  generalization of Euler's little theorem

**THEOREM** $\ $ For primes $\rm\:p \ne q\:,\:$ naturals $\rm\:e\:$ and $\rm\ j,\ k \:\le\: d\ $

$$\rm\quad\quad\ \phi(p^j),\ \phi(q^k)\ |\ e\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ p^j\ q^k\ |\ n^d\ (n^e - 1)\ \ \ \forall\ n\in \mathbb N $$

**Proof** $\ $ If $\rm\ p\ |\ n\ $ then $\rm\ p^j\ |\ n^d\ $ by $\rm\ j\le d\:.\:$ Else $\rm\:n\:$ is coprime to $\rm\: p\:,\:$ so by Euler's little theorem we have: $\ $ mod $\rm\ p^j\:,\ \ n^{\phi(p^j)}\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ n^e\equiv 1\ $ by $\rm\ \phi(p^j)\ |\ e\:.\ $  Thus $\rm\  n^d\ (n^e - 1)\ $ is divisible by $\rm\ p^j\ $ and, similarly it is divisible by $\rm\ q^k\:,\ $ hence it is also divisible by their lcm = product. $\quad$ **QED**

In fact for $\rm\ p = 2,\ j > 2\ $ we can use $\rm\ \phi(2^j)/2\ $ vs. $\rm\ \phi(2^j)\ $ because $\rm\ \mathbb Z/2^j\ $ has multiplicative group $\rm\ C(2)\times C(2^{j-2})\ $ for $\rm\ j> 2\:$. Thus, in fact, $\rm\ 24\ |\ n^3\ (n^2 - 1)\:.$ For more see my post on the [Fermat-Euler-Carmichael theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/modular-exponentiation-using-eulers-theorem/1726#1726)

Comment: Again, the fact that this is more general does not imply my answer was bad.  That technique of splitting into cases will solve a large number of congruence type problems for lower level courses.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}n^5-n^3&=(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)-4n^3+4n\\\\
&=(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)-4(n-1)n(n+1)\end{align}$$

The first expression is a product of 5 consecutive numbers, hence is divisible by $5!$ i.e., by 120. Similarly, the second expression is divisible by $4\cdot (3!)$ i.e., by 24.

Also, $n^5-n^3 = n^2(n-1)n(n+1)$. Clearly, a product of 3 consecutive numbers $(n-1)n(n+1)$ is divisible by 3.
Again, $n^5-n^3 = n^3(n^2-1)$.

If $n$ is even, the R.H.S. is divisible by 8.
If $n$ is odd (equals to $2m+1$, say), then $$n^2-1 = (2m+1)^2 - 1 = 8m(m+1)/2$$ i.e, is divisible by 8 (See [If $n$ is an odd natural number, then $8$ divides $n^{2}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146417/if-n-is-an-odd-natural-number-then-8-divides-n2-1)).

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783) for how to format your mathematics expressions with LaTeX, and see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. If you need to format more advanced math, there are many excellent LaTeX references on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site. If you see a piece of LaTeX you want to know the code for on the site, you can right click on it, go to "Show Math As", then choose "TeX Commands".

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}n^5-n^3&=6\binom{n+1}{3}n^2\\&=4\binom{n+1}{2}\binom{n}{2}n\end{align}$$

Since $6,4\mid n^5-n^3$ we also have that $\text{lcm}(4,6)=12\mid n^5-n^3$