# If x is an odd number, how to prove $x^2=8y+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to let $x=2k+1$ but it ended up proving $k^2+k=2y$ for some $k$ and $y$. What is the correct solution?

Comment: See also: [If $n$ is an odd natural number, then $8$ divides $n^{2}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146417) and [$n\text{ odd}\implies n^2=8k+1$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463258)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another approach, an odd number $x$ is congruent to 1 or 3 mod 4, so try the two cases $x = 4 k + 1$ and $x = 4 k + 3$ and compute $x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Assume that $x=2k+1$ then $$x^2 = 4k(k+1)+1$$

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I don’t see the ration of this and 8y+1

Comment: It's because one of $k$ or $k+1$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  use that $\,x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, and one of two consecutive evens is divisible by $\,4\,$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is odd, then it is congruent to $1$, $3$, $5$ or $7$, modulo $8$. Since
$$
1^2\equiv 1,\quad 3^2\equiv 1,\quad 5^2\equiv 1,\quad 7^2\equiv1\pmod{8}
$$
you're done.

For the “hard” approach, consider that $k(k+1)$ is even.

Comment: I know this statement is correct and x-1 is always a multiple of 8 but can you write this on the test? Feel like it’s not a strict proof

Comment: @MingzhouZhu Sorry, but I can’t know what you’re allowed to use in your test. This is certainly a full proof nonetheless.