# Show that 16 divides $ n^4 -1 $ whenever n is an odd number

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I want to show that  16 divides  $ n^4 -1$ whenever n is odd

I started using the definition of odd with  $ n=2k+1$ and got
 $ n^4=(2k+1)^4=16 k^4+32 k^3+24 k^2+8 k+1$ which means that $n^4-1 = 16 k^4+32 k^3+24 k^2+8 k$

But I am not sure how to go from here or if this is even the correct approach.

Comment: **Hint:**

If $n$ is odd then $n$ is of the form $4k-1$ or $4k+1$.

Comment: Use factorizations. Do you know some standard tricks? E.g. $n^4-1 = (n^2-1)(n^2+1) = (n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$. Now use the hint given by @ÁngelMarioGallegos above.

Comment: Write $n^4 - 1 = (n+1)(n-1)(n^2 + 1)$. If $n$ is odd, one of $n+1$ and $n-1$ is divisible by $4$ and the other two are divisible by $2$. The result follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n^4-1=(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$$

Since $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$, then you can see it as:

$$(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)=((2k+1)^2+1)(2k+2)(2k)=(4k^2+4k+2)(2k+2)(2k)=8(k^2+k+1)(k+1)k$$

But see that $k$ and $k+1$ are consecutive, so one of them has the fourth factor $2$ and that proves that $16\mid n^4-1$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: we can $\rm\color{#c00}{double}$ an $\rm\color{#0a0}{even\ modulus}$ when $\rm\color{#c00}{squaring}$ a congruence, by the Lemma below.

Thus odd $\,n\equiv \pm1\pmod{\!4}\Rightarrow n^2\equiv 1^2\pmod{\!8}\Rightarrow n^4\equiv 1^4\pmod{\!16}. \ \ \small\bf QED$

---

**Lemma** $\ \ a\equiv b\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{2n}}\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large\color{#c00}2}\equiv b^{\large \color{#c00}2}\pmod{\!\color{#c00}2\cdot\color{#0a0}{2n}}\ $

**Proof** $\:\ \color{#0a0}{2\mid 2n\mid a\!-\!b}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#90f}{2\mid a\!+\!b}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#90f}2\cdot\color{#0a0}{2n}\mid(\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})(\color{#90f}{a\!+\!b})=a^{\large 2}-b^2$

**Remark** $ $ [More generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242) the Lemma is a special case of LTE = Lifting The Exponent.

Answer (score 3):

Use congruences: modulo $16$, an odd integer is congruent to $\pm1, \pm 3,\pm 5,\pm 7$, hence its square is congruent to $1^2=1,\; 3^2\equiv -7, 5^2\equiv 9\equiv -7,\;7^2\equiv 1$, so the 4-th powers are congruent to $1,\;7^2\equiv 1,\;9^2\equiv 1,\;1^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$n^4-1=(n^2+1)(n^2-1).$

If $n$ is odd then $n^2+1$ is divisible by $2$ and $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$ is the product of consecutive even numbers so divisible by $8$.