# Mathematical induction proof $n^4-1$ is divisible by $16$ for all odd integers $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm stuck towards the end of proving this, here's my attempt:

$P(3) = 80/16 = 5$, True

$P(k) = k^4-1$

$P(k+1)= (k+1)^4-1$

Expanded $= k^4+4k^3+6k^2+4k+1-1$

This is where I am stuck at.

Sorry for the sloppy formatting im still reading how to  properly write formulas on this site.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hints: 1) you know $k^4-1$ is divisible by 16 (induction hypothesis), so you are left with proving that $4k^3+6k^2+4k+1$ is also divisible by 16; 2) since $k$ is odd, write $k=2a+1$ and substitute. Also, I would start induction from $P(1)$, not $P(3)$.

Comment: you don't need induction:  $n^4-1=(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$; $n^2+1$ is divisible by $2$ and $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$ is the product of consecutive even numbers so divisible by $8$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I can't find it, but this is a dupe.

Comment: [Same problem without the mathematical induction requirement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020763/show-that-16-divides-n4-1-whenever-n-is-an-odd-number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k$ is an odd integer, then next odd integer is $k+2$, not $k+1$. (why?)

You need to prove $P(k+2)=(k+2)^4-1$ is divisible by $16$:
$$\begin{align}(k+2)^4-1&=k^4+8k^3+24k^2+32k+16-1 =\\
&=(k^4-1)+16(2k+1)+8k^2(k+3)\end{align}$$
Note:

1) $k^4-1$ is divisible by $16$ by inductive hypothesis.

2) $16(2k+1)$ is obviously divisible by $16$.

3) $8k^2(k+3)$ is divisible by $16$, because $k+3$ is even. (why?)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

It is true for $n=1$.

assume it is true for some odd $n\ge 1$.

let us prove it is true for $n+\color{red}{2}$.

$$(\color{green}{(n+2)^4-1})-(n^4-1)$$
$$=(n+2)^4-n^4$$
$$=((n+2)^2-n^2)((n+2)^2+n^2)$$

$$=8(n+1)(n^2+2n+2)$$

but
$$n=2k+1$$ and
$$n^4-1=16p$$
with $p,k$ integers.
thus

$$\color{green}{(n+2)^4-1}=$$
$$16p+16(k+1)(n^2+2n+2)$$
nearly done.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality we proved the statement for positive odd integers.

Note that a positive odd integer has the form of $2k-1$ where $k\ge 1$

We proceed with  induction on k.

Let $P(k)$ be  $(2k-1)^4-1$ is a multiple of $16$

For $k=1$, $(2k-1)^4-1=0$ which is a multiple of $16$ so $P(1)$ is true.

Assume that $(2k-1)^4-1$ is a multiple of $16$

We need to show that $(2k+1)^4-1$ is also a multiple of $16$

Note that the binomial theorem implies $$(2k+1)^4 = [(2k-1)+2]^4 = (2k-1)^4+8(2k-1)^3 +24(2k-1)^2+32(2k-1)$$

Thus $$(2k+1)^4 - (2k-1)^4 =8(2k-1)^3 +24(2k-1)^2+32(2k-1)=$$

$$ 8(2k-1)[(2k-1)^2+3(2k-1)+4)]$$

Note that the expression in square bracket is an even integer, so the result is multiple of $16$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ a [$1$-line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2020827/242) shows $\ 8\mid n^2\!-\!1\,\Rightarrow\, 16\mid n^4\!-\!1.\,$  But $\,8\mid n^2\!-\!1$ for odd $\,n\,$ inducts easily

$$\qquad\  {8\mid \color{#c00}{n^2\!-\!1}}\ \Rightarrow\ {8\mid (n\!+\!2)^2-1} = \color{#c00}{n^2\!-\!1} + 4(\underbrace{n\!+\!1}_{\large\rm even})$$