# Calculate $\ a ^{\frac{\color{c00}p^p+1}2}\!\bmod p\,$ for prime $\,p\nmid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The problem is solve/simplify the following expression:

$2•2^\frac{202021^{202021} + 1}{2} \mod 202021$

I start by noticing that 202021 is prime. Then by Euler’s totient theorem:

$a^{\phi(n)} \cong 1 \mod n$

So,
$2^{202020} \cong 1 \mod 202021$

However I’m unsure of where to go from here. I’d appreciate any help!

Comment: Applying [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) as explained in the dupe, we can reduce the exponent to $\,{\large \frac{\color{#c00}p^p+1}2}\bmod{\color{#0a0}{p\!-\!1}},\,$ whose calculation is trivial: hint $\,\color{#c00}p\equiv 1\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{p\!-\!1}}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I see. For the exponent, after applying mod order reduction, I get $2^{101012}$, the resulting expression is $2^{101012} \mod 202021$ which simplifies to $202017$ for me. Can you confirm if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Which way did you compute the exponent $\bmod 202020?$ It's not completely trivial due to the division by $2.\ $ Did you use Euler/QR to finish?

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes. I noticed that $202021$ can be reduced modulo $202020$ using your hint as $202021 \equiv 1 \mod 202020$, hence $202021^{202021} \equiv 1^{202021} \mod 202020$ which is just $1$. The exponent is reduced to merely $\frac{1+3}{2}$. Was I correct?

Comment: No, we need to double the modulus to balance the division by $2$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3273923/242). $\ \ $

Comment: That would leave $\mod 404040$, but I’m not sure what follows, since $202021^{202021} \mod 404040$ would still be $1$. @BillDubuque

Comment: No, $\,n := p^p\equiv 1\pmod{\!p\!-\!1}\,$ so $\,n\equiv 1\,$ or $\,\color{#c00}p\pmod{\!2(p\!-\!1)}.\,$ It must be $\,n\equiv\color{#c00}p\,$ since only that is correct $\!\bmod 8\,$ (where $\,p^2\equiv 1\Rightarrow p^{\rm odd}\equiv p).\,$ Thus $\,k := p^p+1\equiv \color{#c00}p+1\pmod{2(p\!-\!1))},\,$ so $\,k/2\equiv (p+1)/2\pmod{\!p\!-\!1}\ \ $

Comment: **Or** [by $\rm \mu LTE\!:$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2020827/242) $\bmod p\!-\!1\!:\ \color{#0a0}{p\equiv 1}\,$ so $\bmod{\color{#c00}2(p\!-\!1)}\!:\ \color{#0a0}{p^{\large\color{#c00}2}\equiv 1^{\large\color{#c00}2}},\,$ so $\,p^{\large p}\equiv p^{\large 1+2k}\equiv p(\color{#0a0}{p^{\large\color{#c00}2}})^k\equiv p\ \ $