# Finding the GCD in a function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> I am currently stuck on a number theory problem.
> The question is to determine the GCD of every number in the form $p^6-7p^2+6$, where $p$ is a prime number and greater than or equal to $11$.

My approach:
After a substitution and factoring I came to factor it as $(p^2-2)(p^2+3)(p-1)(p+1)$.
By examining the first $10$ cases I come to the conclusion that the GCD is $672$, as the factors $2^5$, $3$ and $7$ are always present in all the cases. Just I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: You don't need to fully factor it.  $\,f(x) = x^3-7x+6\,$  has roots $\,x=1,-3\,$ so it has factor $\,(x-1)(x+3).\,$ Putting $x=p^2$ we deduce that $\,f(p^2)\,$ has factor $\,(p^2-1)(p^2+3),\,$ hence $\,8\cdot 4\mid f(p^2)\,$ by $\,8\mid p^2-1,\ 4\mid p^2+3,\,$  [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146440/242) ${\rm odd}^2\equiv 1\,$ both mod $4$ & $8.\,$ See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759047/finding-the-gcd-in-a-function#comment10103145_4759055) for another way. Finally, the factors $3$ and $7$ follow immediately from Fermat's little Theorem.

Comment: $$\begin{align} &\bmod \color{#0a0}7\!:\,\ p\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,  \color{#c00}{p^6\equiv 1}\Rightarrow \ \, \color{#c00}{p^6}\ -\ \color{#0a0}7p^2+6\equiv \color{#c00}1-\color{#0a0}0(p^2)+6\equiv 0\\[.4em]
&\bmod 3\!:\,\ p\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{p^2\equiv 1}\Rightarrow (\color{#c00}{p^2})^3\!-7\color{#c00}{p^2}\!+6\equiv \color{#c00}1^3\!-7(\color{#c00}1)+6\equiv 0\\
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: I removed the `prime-numbers` tag since that is a red herring. The proof works for any set of odd integers not divisible by $7,\,$ and includes $11$ & $13$ (or any other index subset yielding $672$ as gcd).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $p^6-7p^2+6$ is divisible by $2^5,3,7$ for any prime $p\geq 11$:
for $p:=2k+1$,
$$\begin{align}
p^6-7p^2+6&=(p^2-2)(p^2+3)(p^2-1)\\
&=(p^2-2)(4k^2+4k+4)(4k^2+4k)\\
&=2^4(p^2-2)(k^2+k+1)\underbrace{k(k+1)}_{\text{even}}
\equiv 0 \pmod{2^5},
\end{align}$$
and, by Fermat's theorem,
$$\begin{align}
&p^6-7p^2+6\equiv p^6-p^2=p^2(p^2-1)(p^2+1)\equiv 0 \pmod{3},\\
&p^6-7p^2+6\equiv p^6-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}.
\end{align}$$
Therefore $2^5\cdot 3\cdot 7=672$ divides $N$, the desired gcd.

Since $11$ and $13$ are primes $\geq 11$, we have that
$$\gcd(11^6−7\cdot 11^2+6,13^6−7\cdot 13^2+6)=672$$
is divisible by $N$ ($N$ divides both numbers $11^6−7\cdot 11^2+6$, $13^6−7\cdot 13^2+6$).

Hence we may conclude that $N=672$.

Comment: You should say *why* it "suffices to verify that...."

Comment: Your edit did not completely fix the above, since you don't justify why the gcd $M \mid \gcd(f_{11},f_{13}).\,$ You are implicitly using a property of gcds that should be made *explicit*, i.e. you are using w/o justification that $\,\gcd(f_{11},f_{13},f_{17},f_{19}\ldots)\mid \gcd(f_{11},f_{13})\ \ $

Comment: Still incomplete. One straightforward way to deduce that key divisibility is as follows $$m := \gcd(f_{11},f_{13},f_{17},\ldots)\mid f_{11},f_{13}\,\Longrightarrow\, m\mid \gcd(f_{11},f_{13})\qquad\qquad $$ by the [gcd universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198787/242) $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for your precious comments. OP will appreciate them too

Comment: A bit easier is as follows (this also avoids pulling out of a hat (like magic) the stated factorization of $p^6-7p^2+6).\,$ [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146440/242) that  $\bmod 8\!:\  {\rm odd}^2\equiv 1\,$ so $\,p^2 = 8j+1,\,$ so

$$\begin{align}
\bmod 32\!:\,\ p^2((p^2)^2\!-7) &\,=\,(8j+1)((8j+1)^2\!-7)\\[.2em]
               &\,\equiv\, (8j+1)(16j-6),\ \ \color{lightgrey}{{\rm by}\,\ \ 8^2\equiv 0}\\[.2em]
               &\,\equiv\, -6,\ \ \color{lightgrey}{{\rm by}\,\ \ 8(16)\equiv 0\equiv 1(16)+8(-6)} \end{align}\qquad$$