# Number theory congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $n^{12} - a^{12}$ is divisible by $91$ if $n$ and $a$ are co prime to $91$

What I tried:

- $91$ divides $n^{12}-a^{12}$
- Therefore $n^{12}-a^{12}=91k$
- But $91=13\times7$
- $n^{12}-a^{12}=(13\times7)k$
- $n^{12}=(13\times7)k+a^{12}$
- $n^{12}$ divides $91$
- Therefore $n$ is co prime to $91$

Comment: This is hard to read...[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: To your question:  since $91=7\times 13$, solve the problem $\pmod 7$ and $\pmod {13}$ first.

Comment: ... noting that $12=13-1$ and $\frac{12}{2}=7-1$

Comment: What you've tried;  1) $91$ divides $n^{12}-a^{12}$.  You don't know that so you can't assume that.  That is what you are trying to prove.  5) $n^{12} = (13*7)k + a^{12}$ so 6) $n^{12}$ divides $91$.  No it doesn't!  $a^{12}\ne 0$ so you have a remainder.  $n^{12}$ is a twelvth power so unless $n=1$ then $n^{12}\ge 4096$.  ... But this entire stuff, is assuming what you want to prove.  You can't do that.

Comment: And if $n^{12}$ divides $91$ and $n \ne 1$ then that means $n$ is *NOT* coprime to $91$.  .... Which you don't need to prove.  You were *given* it.  You *cant* assume what you want to prove and work to the beginning with what you were given.  Proofs don't go backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $n,a$ are integers, relatively prime to $91$.

Since $91=7\cdot 13$, it follows that $n,a$ are relatively prime to $7$ and $13$.

Applying Fermat's little Theorem with the prime $13$, we get
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
n^{12}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
a^{12}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\
\end{cases}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&n^{12}-a^{12}\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&13{\,{\mid}\,}\bigl(n^{12}-a^{12}\bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and applying Fermat's little Theorem with the prime $7$, we get
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
n^{6}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
a^{6}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\
\end{cases}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\begin{cases}
n^{12}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
a^{12}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\
\end{cases}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&n^{12}-a^{12}\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&7{\,{\mid}\,}\bigl(n^{12}-a^{12}\bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, since $7{\,{\mid}\,}\bigl(n^{12}-a^{12}\bigr)$ and $13{\,{\mid}\,}\bigl(n^{12}-a^{12}\bigr)$, it follows that $91{\,{\mid}\,}\bigl(n^{12}-a^{12}\bigr)$.

As regards your proof attempt, the problem doesn't ask you to prove that $n$ is relatively prime to $91$.

It's *given* that $n,a$ are relatively prime to $91$, and the goal is to prove that $91{\,{\mid}\,}\bigl(n^{12}-a^{12}\bigr)$.

Note that in the first line of your proof attempt, you assume what you are required to prove, and of course, that's not a legal assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Below put $\rm\: n=7\cdot 13,\  f=12$

**Theorem** $\  $ If $\rm\ n\in \mathbb N\ $ has prime factorization $\rm\:n = p_1^{e_{\:1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and $\rm\ \phi(p_i^{e_{\:i}})\ |\ f\,$ for all $\,\rm i,\,$ then $\rm\ n\ |\  a^f-b^f\ $ for all $\rm\: a,b\in \mathbb Z\,$ coprime to $\rm\,n$.

**Proof** $\ $ By hypothesis $\rm\:a\:$ and $\rm\:b\:$ are coprime to $\rm\: p_i\:$ thus by [Euler's phi theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $\rm\ mod\ q = p_i^{e_{\:i}}\!:\: \ a^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1\equiv b^{\phi(q)}\: \Rightarrow\ a^f\equiv 1\equiv b^f\, $ so $\,\rm a^f-b^f\equiv 0,\,$ by $\rm\: \phi(q)\ |\ f\:.\ $  Therefore, since all $\rm\ p_i^{e_{\:i}}\ |\  a^f - b^f\\ $ so too does their lcm = product = $\rm\: n\:.\:$
**Remark**  $ $ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53679/242) for a generalization for all $\rm\,a,b\,$ (i.e. not necessarily coprime to $\,\rm\,n)$

Answer (score 0):

Two things should leap to mind.  And a third thing comes with practice.

1) $91 = 13*7$ so to prove $91|M$ it will work to prove a) $7|M$ and b) $13|M$.  If you can prove a) and b) you are done.

2) $n^{12} - a^{12} = (n^6 - a^6)(n^6 + a^6) = (n^3 - a^3)(n^3 + a^3)(n^6 + a^6)=....$.  The expression $n^{12}-a^{12}$ is "very" factorable.  If we can prove that of the many factors that $7$ and/or $13$ must divide at least one of the factors that will help.  There are so many factors something working out is likely.

And with practice:

3) $12 = 13 -1$ and $13$ is prime.  So Euler's Theorem/Fermats Little Theorem will probably come into play.

.....

Factor $n^{12} -a^{12}$ completely.

$n^{12}-a^{12} = (n-a)(n^11 + n^10a + .... +na^{11} + a^{12})=$

$(n^2 - a^2)(n^{10} + n^8a^2 + .... + n^2a^8 + a^{10})=$

$(n^3 - a^3)(n^9 + n^6a^3 + n^3a^6 + a^9)=$

$(n^4-a^4)(n^8 + n^4a^4 + a^8)=$

$(n^6 - a^6)(n^6 + a^6) =$

$(n^6+a^6)(n^3 + a^3)(n^2+a^2)(n+a)(n-a)$.

Those probably have different remainders when divided by $7$ or $13$.  One of them can probably be proven to be $0$. but... that may be hard to figure out.  Let's put a pin in it and look at 3)

3) Fermat's little theorem states if $\gcd(k,13)=1$ then $k^{12}\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$.  And $n,a$ are coprime to $91$ so they are coprime to $13$ so

$a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ and $n^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ so $n^{12}-a^{12}\equiv 1-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 13$ so $13|(n^{12} - a^{12})$.

So now we just need to prove $7|n^{12} - a^{12}$....

Back to the factoring... oh, wait!....

Fermat's Little Theorem states $n^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and $a^6\equiv \pmod 7$ so $n^{12}-a^{12} = (n^6- a^6)(n^6 + a^6)\equiv (1-1)(n^6 + a^6)\equiv 0 \pmod 7$ so $7|n^{12}-a^{12}$.

And we are done!

We didn't need to do that factoring stuff at all.

Still it'd be interesting to see if we can do it by considering just the factors.  But we don't have to.