# Polynomials that induce the zero function mod $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

- Which polynomials induce the zero function mod $n$?

In particular:

- What is the polynomial of least degree that induces the zero function mod $n$?
- What is the monic polynomial of least degree that induces the zero function mod $n$?

These are not vacuous questions because of the following general result:

> If $r$ is the maximum exponent in the prime factorization of $n$, then $x \mapsto x^{r+\lambda (n)}-x^r$ is the zero function mod $n$. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length)]

Here, $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

- When is $x^{r+\lambda (n)}-x^r$ the monic polynomial of least degree that induces the zero function mod $n$?

Fermat's theorem implies that $x^n-x$ is the answer for $n$ prime: all polynomials that induce the zero function mod $n$ are a multiple of $x^n-x$.
How can this be generalized to composite $n$?

Here are some other examples:
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
n & L_n: \text{least degree} & M_n: \text{least degree monic}
\\ 2 & x^2+x
\\ 3 & x^3-x
\\ 4 & 2(x^2+x) & x^4-x^2
\\ 5 & x^5-x
\\ 6 & 3(x^2+x) & x^3-x
\\ 7 & x^7-x
\\ 8 & 4(x^2+x) & x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x = x(x+1)(x^2+x+2)
\\ 9 & 3(x^3-x) & x^8-x \quad (???)
\\ 10 & 5(x^2+x) & x^5-x
\\ 11 & x^{11}-x
\\ 12 & 6(x^2+x) & x^4+5x^2+6x = x(x+1)(x^2-x+6)
\\ 13 & x^{13}-x
\\ 14 & 7(x^2+x) & ???
\\ 15 & 5(x^3-x) & x^5-x
\\ 21 & 7(x^3-x) & ???
\\ 24 & 12(x^2+x) & x^4+2x^3+11x^2+10x = x(x+1)(x^2+x+10)
\end{array}
$$

It seems clear that $L_{2m}=m(x^2+x)$, because $x^2+x$ is always even.
More generally,

- Is $L_{pq} = qL_p$ and $M_{pq}=L_q$ for $p<q$ primes?
- If $n=pm$ and $p$ is smallest prime divisor of $n$, then is $L_{pm}=mL_p$?

Corrections and additions welcome.
Please collect partial results as answers.

Comment: Motivated by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386902/finding-equivalent-polynomials-mod-n

Comment: For $14$ monic it is $x^7-x$. Note that this works, and if a smaller monic polynomial would work, then it would work modulo 7.

Comment: More generarily, for $n=pq$ with  $p-1|q-1$ it should be $x^q-x$. So $x^7-x$ should also be the smallest for $n=21$.

Comment: For $9$, the product of 6 consecutive linear terms is a smaller one. So $(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$ works. I am not sure if anything smaller works.

Comment: Without requiring monic polynomials, $p(x)=n$ is always an option of degree $0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that doesn't count. I mean *nonzero* polynomials.

Comment: For $n=16$ I think that $8X(X-1)$ and $X^4(X^2-1)(X-1)$, with the second one just a guess[using here that for odd integer $X^2-1$ is divisible by 8]. For $n=8$, for the same reason $X^3(X^2-1)$ always works, same degree but looks "cleaner".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is the zero polynomial in $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z[X]$. But I see, as it is stated, it can be understood that the OP is looking for polynomails over $\mathbb Z$ which induce the 0 function.

Comment: If $p(x)$ is a solution then so is $p(x+1)$ and hence so is $p(x+1)-p(x).$ but that is smaller degrees, so it means that $p(x+1)=p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_n[x]$ (Non-monic case.)

Comment: For $n=5$ the Polynomial is equivalent to $Q(X)=(X-2)(X-2)X(X+1)(X+2) \pmod{5}$. Note that $Q(X)$ is trivially $0$ both modulo 3 and modulo 8. This means that this is the best monic answer for $n=5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 60, 120$.

Comment: Also, if $p$ is minimal monic, then its degree $d$ must not be relatively prime to $n$ since $q(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$ is of smaller degree, and has lead coefficient $d.$ So multiply by the inverse of $d$ and get a monic again.

Comment: My edited answer shows that your last conjecture is true... But your $M_8$ is wrong, I think it needs to start with $x^4$, so seems only a typo :)

Comment: I believe I have now satisfactorily answered all the questions in this post, in [my answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4070878). Please take a look if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which polynomials induce the zero function mod $n$?

As proved in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4070413), the polynomials that induce the zero function mod $n$ are precisely those that, when written in the form
$$f(x) = \sum_{k} c_k x^{\underline k},$$
satisfy the property that $c_k$ is divisible by $n\,/\gcd(n, k!)$, for each $k$. (Here, $x^{\underline k}$ is the "falling factorial": $x^{\underline k} = x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$.)

---

That answers the first question, and to answer the other questions:

> What is the polynomial of least degree that induces the zero function mod $n$?

I'm assuming you don't accept polynomials like $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = n$ or $f(x) = nx + 2n$, etc, i.e. you want the coefficients to be nonzero mod $n$. When $k$ is less than the smallest factor of $n$, we get $\gcd(n, k!) = 1$, which means that $c_k$ is a multiple of $n$. We can take $c_k$ nonzero mod $n$, when $\gcd(n, k!) > 1$, which happens when $k$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$, say $p$. Then we need $c_k$ to be a multiple of $n / \gcd(n, k!) = n / p$, so we can take $c_k$ to be $n/p$ and all other coefficients $0$, so that $f(x) = (n/p) x^{\underline p} = (n/p) x(x-1)\cdots(x-p+1)$. Other polynomials of degree $p$ may also be possible.

This gives the following table, as in the question:

$$
\begin{array}{rll}
n & L_n\text{ from question} & L_n\text{ from this answer}
\\ 2 & x^2+x & (2/2)x^{\underline 2} = x^2 - x
\\ 3 & x^3-x & (3/3)x^{\underline 3} = x(x-1)(x-2) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x
\\ 4 & 2(x^2+x) & (4/2)x^{\underline 2} = 2(x^2 - x)
\\ 5 & x^5-x & (5/5)x^{\underline 5} = x^5 - 10x^4 + 35x^3 - 50x^2 + 24x
\\ 6 & 3(x^2+x) & (6/2)x^{\underline 2} = 3(x^2 - x)
\\ 7 & x^7-x & (7/7)x^{\underline 7} = …
\\ 8 & 4(x^2+x) & (8/2)x^{\underline 2} = 4(x^2 - x)
\\ 9 & 3(x^3-x) & (9/3)x^{\underline 3} = 3(x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x)
\\ 10 & 5(x^2+x) & (10/2)x^{\underline 2} = 5(x^2-x)
\\ 11 & x^{11}-x & (11/11)x^{\underline{11}} = …
\\ 12 & 6(x^2+x) & (12/2)x^{\underline 2} = 6(x^2 - x)
\\ 13 & x^{13}-x & (13/13)x^{\underline{13}} = …
\\ 14 & 7(x^2+x) & (14/2)x^{\underline 2} = 7(x^2 - x)
\\ 15 & 5(x^3-x) & (15/3)x^{\underline 3} = 5(x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x)
\\ 21 & 7(x^3-x) & (21/3)x^{\underline 3} = 7(x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x)
\\ 24 & 12(x^2+x) & (24/2)x^{\underline 2} = 12(x^2 - x)
\end{array}
$$

so you see it matches in each case (is congruent mod $n$). It's not too hard to prove that for prime $p$, $x^{\underline p}$ is the same as $x^p - x$ modulo $p$.

---

> What is the monic polynomial of least degree that induces the zero function mod $n$?

For this we need $c_d = 1$ where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial, and this must be a multiple of $n / \gcd(n, d!)$, so $n / \gcd(n, d!)$ must be $1$, or in other words $\gcd(n, d!) = n$ which means that $n$ divides $d!$. This is called the [Kempner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kempner_function&oldid=849909068). So we can take $c_d = 1$ and all other $c_k$ to be $0$.

This gives the following table, for the examples in the question:

$$
\begin{array}{rll}
n & M_n\text{ from question} & M_n\text{ from this answer}
\\ 2 & x^2+x & x^{\underline 2}
\\ 3 & x^3-x & x^{\underline 3}
\\ 4 & x^4-x^2 & x^{\underline 4} = x^4 - 6 x^3 + 11 x^2 - 6 x
\\ 5 & x^5-x & x^{\underline 5}
\\ 6 & x^3-x & x^{\underline 3} = x^3 - 3 x^2 + 2 x
\\ 7 & x^7-x & x^{\underline 7}
\\ 8 & x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x & x^{\underline 4}
\\ 9 & x^8-x \quad (???) & x^{\underline 6}
\\ 10 & x^5-x & x^{\underline 5}
\\ 11 & x^{11}-x & x^{\underline{11}}
\\ 12 & x^4+5x^2+6x & x^{\underline 4}
\\ 13 & x^{13}-x & x^{\underline{13}}
\\ 14 & ??? & x^{\underline 7}
\\ 15 & x^5-x & x^{\underline 5}
\\ 21 & ??? & x^{\underline 7}
\\ 24 & x^4+2x^3+11x^2+10x & x^{\underline 4}
\end{array}
$$

which answers some of the $???$s in the question, corrects one of them ($M_9$ has degree $6$, not $8$), gives the same polynomials mod $n$ for some $n$, and some truly different (though they can be checked to work: so $M_n$ is not unique as a polynomial, though the polynomial *function* (mod $n$) itself is unique).

---

> When is $x^{r+\lambda (n)}-x^r$ the monic polynomial of least degree that induces the zero function mod $n$?

As "the monic polynomial of least degree" is not unique (see the examples just above), the relevant question is to ask when the degree matches. For this to happen, $r + \lambda(n)$ must be the [Kempner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kempner_function&oldid=849909068) of $n$ (let's call it $K(n)$), i.e. the smallest $k$ such that $n$ divides $k!$. This happens when either:

- $n = 4$, or
- $n = 12$, or
- $n = p_1 p_2 \ldots p_m$ a product of distinct primes and $p_m - 1$ is divisible by $p - 1$ whenever $p$ is any of the primes $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_m$. (This case includes the cases of $n$ being prime, $n$ being $2p$, or $3p$, or $2 \cdot 3 \cdot p$, or $5p$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, or $11p$ where $p > 11$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$, etc.)

The proof is as follows. First, for prime powers $n = p^r$, note that $\lambda(n) = p^{r-1}(p-1)$ while $K(n) \le rp$ (it's equal when $r \le p$, and smaller for larger $r$). So for them to be equal, we need $r + p^{r-1}(p-1) \le rp$ which happens only when $r=1$ or for $(p, r) = (2, 2)$. Next, when $n$ has prime factorization $n = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_m^{e_m}$, the Carmichael function $\lambda(n) = \operatorname{lcm}(\lambda(p_1^{e_1}), \ldots, \lambda(p_m^{e_m}))$. Meanwhile, the RHS $K(n)$ is $\max(K(p_1^{e_1}), \ldots, K(p_m^{e_m}))$. Now if the maximum on the right is attained at a certain $J$, then the same inequality gives that either $e_J = 1$ and $r = 1$ so $n$ is a product of distinct primes and the property above needs to hold so that the LCM of the values $(p_j - 1)$ doesn't exceed $p_m - 1$, or else the special case of $J = 1$, $p_1 = 2$, $e_1 = 2$, and other primes if any are less than $2^2$ so $n$ is either $2^2 = 4$ or $2^2 \cdot 3 = 12$.

---

To answer the final two questions (and the comment before them):

> It seems clear that $L_{2m}=m(x^2+x)$

Yes we can take $m(x^2 + x)$; note that our above method gives the polynomial $(2m/m)x^{\underline 2} = m(x^2 - x)$ which is the same mod $2m$.

> Is $L_{pq} = qL_p$ and $M_{pq}=L_q$ for $p<q$ primes?

For $L_p$ we can take $(p/p)x^{\underline p}$ and for $L_{pq}$ we can take $(pq/p) x^{\underline p}$, so yes for the first part. Similarly, for the second part, we can take $L_q = x^{\underline q}$ and $M_{pq}$ to be $x^{\underline q}$ as well, as $pq$ divides $q!$ when $p < q$.

> If $n=pm$ and $p$ is smallest prime divisor of $n$, then is $L_{pm}=mL_p$?

Yes, as above, for $L_p$ we take $x^{\underline p}$ and for $L_{pm}$ we take $(pm/p) x^{\underline p}$.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer!

Comment: @lhf You're welcome, and thanks for the nice question, which helped me check/verify my understanding :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Edited and improved**

Using the fact that the product of any $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$ we immediately get

**Lemma 1** Let $R_n(X)=X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-n+1)$. Then $R(X)$ is trivial $\pmod{n!}$.

**Lemma2:** Let $P(X)=a_kX^k+..+a_1X+a_0$ and let $p$ be prime. If $P(X)$ is trivial modulo $p$ and $p$ does not divide all coefficients of $P(X)$ then $k \geq p$.

**Proof:** Since $P(X)$ has $p$ roots in the field $\ZZ_p$, it has degree at least $p$ modulo $p$. Then $k \geq p$.

---

As consequences we get immediately:

**Lemma 3:** If $p$ is prime, and $n$ is so that $p|n$ and $n |p!$ then 
$$
M_n=X(X-1)(X_2)...(X-p+1)=: R_p
$$

[Or another polynomial of same degree, namely $M_n=R_p+Q(X)L_n(X)$ for some $Q(X)$.]

Proof: Since $n|p!$, by Lemma 1 $R_p(X) $ is trivial modulo $n$. By Lemma2, $deg(M_n) \geq p$.
\qed

**Lemma 4** If $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$, and $n$ is square free, then 
$$L_n=\frac{n}{p}(X^p-X)$$

**Proof** It is clear that this polynomial works. We show next $\deg(L_n) \geq p$.

Let $L_n=a_kX^k+....a_1X+a_0$. Take the first coefficient $a_l$ which is not divisible by $n$. Then, there exists a prime $q|n$ such that $q \nmid a_l$.

By Lemma 2$deg(L_n) \geq q \geq p$.

**Final Note:** Your $M_8$ is wrong. Note that if $n$ is even then $8|n(n-2)$ and if $n$ is odd $8|(n-1)(n+1)$.

I think that it is easy to show that $M_8=(X-2)(X-1)X(X+1)$ or something equivalent $\pmod{8}$. THis also works for $M_{24}$.

Comment: $R_n(X)$ is sometimes called the "falling factorial" and is written $(X)_n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you, should I maybe change notation in the answer or make a note at the end? I

Comment: No real reason to change it.

Comment: Do we really need $n$ to be square-free in Lemma 4? It seems to work for $n=4,8,9,24$

Comment: @Ihf I suspect it is not needed, but I don't see the proof without it :)

Answer (score 2):

Not complete answers, but too large for comment. I have the results, when $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_{k}^{\alpha_k}$:

> *Non-monic case:* The minimal degree is exactly $\min p_i.$
>
> *Monic case:* The minimal degree is the maximum of the degrees for each $p_i^{\alpha_i}.$ The degree of $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ must be divisible by $p_i$ and is at most $\alpha_ip_i.$ This is not the absolute minimum, for example when $p=2$ and $\alpha=3,$ the minimal degree for $8$ is $4<6=p\alpha.$
>
> My conjecture is that the minimal monic degree $d$ for $p^k$ is the smallest $d$ such that $\nu_p(d!)\geq k.$
>
> If that is true, then if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then the minimal monic degree is the minimal $d$ such that each $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ divides $d!.$

**Non-monic case:**

If $d(n)$ is the smallest degree for $n$ in the non-monic case, we can get, for any $m.n,$ $d(mn)=\min(d(m),d(n)).$

This is because if $p_m(x)$ is a minimal polynomial for $m$ then we take $np_m(x).$

This means that if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots$ then $d(n)=\min_i d\left(p_i\right).$ But when $p$ is prime, $d(p)=p,$ so we get $d(n)=\min_i p_i.$

**Monic case:**

If $D(n)$ is the smallest degree of a monic, then when $\gcd(m,n)=1$ you have that $D(mn)=\max (D(m),D(n)).$

This is because if $p_m,p_n$ are the corresponding monic polynomials with $D(m)\geq D(n)$ you can apply Chinese remainder theorem coefficient by coefficient to find a polynomial $P_{mn}$ so that:

$$\begin{align}P_{mn}(x)&\equiv p_m(x)\pmod{m}\\
P_{mn}(x)&\equiv x^{D(m)-D(n)}p_n(x)\pmod{n}\end{align}$$

Since both polynomials are monic and of degree equal to the $D(m),$ we get $P_{mn}$ monic and $P_{mn}(x)$ satisfies your conditions.

We also have that $D\left(p^{\alpha}\right)\leq p\alpha$ since $(x^p-x)^{\alpha}$ is monic of degree $p\alpha$ and satisfies our conditions.

---

As noted in my comments above, if $p(x)$ is always zero modulo $n$ then so is $p(x+1)-p(x).$

In the monic case, this means if $p(x)$ is minimal then $d=\deg p(x)$ must have a common factor with $n,$ since otherwise $q(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$ is of smaller degree with leading coefficient $d$ so we solve $du-nv=1$ and take $r(x)=uq(x)-nvx^{d-1}$ which is monic of smaller degree and satisfies our condition.

---

To finish the question, one needs to compute a value of $D(p^{\alpha}),$ which we know is divisible by $p$ and $\leq p\alpha.$

---

**Conjecture**

My guess is that $D\left(p^{\alpha}\right)$ is the smallest $d$ such that $\nu_p(d!)\geq \alpha.$ In particular, if $\alpha\leq p$ then $d=\alpha p.$
If $\alpha=p+1$ then $\nu_p\left((p^2)!\right)=p+1.$ Do $D(p^p)=D(p^{p+1})=p^2.$

This is definitely an upper bound, because the falling factorial $(x)_d$ is monic and of degree $d$ and is always divisible by $p^{\nu_p(d)}.$

Comment: "If d(n) is the smallest degree for n in the non-monic case, we can get, for any m.n, $d(mn)=min(d(m),d(n))$." The part which is not clear to me is why do we get equality.  $\leq$ is clear, but for $\geq$ what if you get $0$ when you go from $\pmod{mn}$ to $\pmod{n}$?

Comment: Your conjecture is correct, I think. See the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070051/how-many-distinct-polynomials-are-there-mod-n) I posted earlier today. See also [Kempner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kempner_function&oldid=849909068).

Answer (score 1):

These papers characterize the polynomials that induce the zero function mod $n$:

- [On polynomial functions (mod $n$)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(74)90031-6) by Singmaster (1974)
- [Polynomials and their residue systems](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1921-1501173-4) by Kempner (1921)

Kempner's paper is closer to what I have in mind. I'll have to check it more closely.

I came across Kempner's paper in the paper [A basis for residual polynomials in $n$ variables](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1935-1501784-6) by Litzinger (1935).

Comment: (Deleted earlier comment.) After posting an answer to a related question I posted ([How many “distinct” polynomials are there mod ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070051/how-many-distinct-polynomials-are-there-mod-n)), and reading up on some related material (including a nice 2000 article by Manjul Bhargava that generalizes things), it appears that Singmaster's 1974 paper was written without knowledge of Kempner's 1921 work which already answered the same questions. Nevertheless, that he independently got the same expressions is reassuring, that there are no mistakes here!