# Smallest $n >1$ such that $a^n = a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ for all $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

A necessary condition for such an $n$ to exist is that $m$ be square-free. However, is it sufficient? If yes, how do you find the smallest such $n$?

Examples: In $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ $n = 3$ works: working mod 6, we have $$1^3 = 1, 2^3 = 8 \equiv 2, 3^3 = 27 \equiv 3, 4^3 = 64 \equiv 4, 5^3 = 125 \equiv 5.$$

Similarly, in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ $n = 5$ works. Note that $ 6 = 2 \cdot 3$ and $10 = 2 \cdot 5$ are both square-free.

If $n$ is not square free, say $n = 45 = 3^2 \cdot 9$, then we can divide $n$ be some prime whose square divides $n$ to get a number $a$ (in this case $45/3 = 15$), and $a$ to any power $n > 1$ is always 0 mod n, so in particular $a^n$ will never be $a$ mod $n$.

Now consider $m = 1309 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$. Is there an $n > 1$ such that $1^n = 1, \ldots, 1308^n = 1308$ (mod 1309)?

Comment: ever heard of the euler $\phi$ function?

Comment: @Exodd Yes. And?

Comment: Well, if $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then you have $a^{\phi(n) +1 }\equiv a \pmod n$

Comment: @AnuragA $8$ is not squarefree, in fact $2^3 \equiv 0$

Comment: @Exodd I missed the square free part of the question.

Comment: @AnuragA Yeah, I noticed

Comment: @Exodd It is not necessarily the case that $n = \phi(m) + 1$ is the smallest such value. For instance, try $m = 15$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Probably it is $lcm(p_i-1) + 1$ where $p_i|m$ then

Comment: @Junglemath I believe it should be $n = \lambda(m) + 1$, where $\lambda(m)$ denotes the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Comment: @Exodd I also suspect this

Comment: What happens in the case when $a$ is not relatively prime to $m$?

Comment: This is a product of distinct prime order fields, so the only things that contribute are the orders of their cyclic multiplicative groups.  That seems to make the $lcm(p_i-1)+1$ formula obvious.

Comment: See also the dual question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164524/largest-modulus-for-fermat-type-polynomial and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387540/polynomials-that-induce-the-zero-function-mod-n

Answer (score 2):

If $m = p_1p_2 \cdots p_k$, then the smallest such $n$ will be
$$
1 + \lambda(m) = 1 + \operatorname{lcm}(p_1 -1,\dots,p_k-1).
$$
To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that, by the Chinese Remainder theorem, we have
$$
a^n \equiv a \pmod {m} \iff  a^n \equiv a \pmod {p_i} \text{ for } i = 1,\dots,k.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's Theorem,and since for every prime there exists a generator of the multiplicative gorup, if $m$ is prime, then $n=m$ itself is the smallest exponent such that
$$a^n \equiv a \pmod m$$

Given now a squarefree composite $m=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot \dots\cdot p_k$, let $s = lcm(p_i-1) +1$. Take now any $0\le a<m$ and inspect the remainder modulus $p_i$
$$
a \equiv a_i \pmod {p_i}
$$
and notice that
$$
a^s \equiv a_i^s = a_i^{(p_i-1)r}a_i\equiv a_i \pmod {p_i}.
$$
by CRT (Chinese remainder theorem), you find that $a^s \equiv a \pmod m$. To prove that $s$ is the least possible, take $g_i$ a generator of $\mathbb Z_{p_i}^\times$ and notice that if $g_i^n\equiv g_i\pmod m$ then
$$
 g_i^n \equiv g_i\pmod {p_i} \implies p_i-1 | n-1
$$
for every $i$. As a consequence, $lcm(p_i-1)|n-1$, so either $s$ or $1$ is the least possible exponent. But you wanto $n>1$.