# Polynomials vanishing identically on $\mathbb Z/n$ or $(\mathbb Z / n)^\times$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let us restrict ourselves to $n = p^k$, for some prime $p$.
I ask:

1. what primitive polynomials $P$ vanish identically on $\mathbb Z /n$ ?
2. what primitive polynomials $P$ vanish identically on $(\mathbb Z /n)^\times$?

Regarding no 2, it should be clear that $P$ could be reduced modulo $X^{\varphi(n)} - 1$, so a possible preliminary question would be: do there exist primitive polynomials of degree less than $\varphi(n)$ that vanish identically on $(\mathbb Z /n)^\times$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387540/polynomials-that-induce-the-zero-function-mod-n

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary question: $x^2 - 1$ vanishes on $(\mathbb Z/8)^\times$ but $\varphi(8) = 4$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To be clear: $x^2-1$ vanishes on $(\mathbb Z/8)^\times$ (which I assume is the notation here for the residues relatively prime to $8$, but not on all of $\mathbb Z/8$, for example not when $x=2$.