# Finding monic integer polynomial of lowest degree with all outputs multiple of an integer

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I was working with a student on the following problem (source unknown)

> Let $f(n)$ be the minimum degree of a monic polynomial $p$ such that for all integers $m$, $p(m)$ is a multiple of $n$. Evaluate $f(10^{10})$.

Clearly, $f(10^{10})\leq45$ as $$p(x)=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{44}(x+k)$$satisfies the requirements, but we are struggling to show that this is optimal (or if not, how we can do better).

Comment: Interesting.  What about smaller values?  Is the answer always given by the least integer $k$ with $n\,|\,k!$   ?

Comment: @lulu That's my theory, but I've failed to prove it.

Comment: Well, for small numbers it shouldn't be hard to check, no?  Try $6$ for instance.

Comment: @lulu It's true for $6$. I just brute forced all of the possibilities.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387540/polynomials-that-induce-the-zero-function-mod-n) is a (closely) related question with some results and some links (which I did not study).

Comment: @lulu From that link, it seems as though it is believed that our theory is correct, although the proof is not known. I don't get how this question is meant to be solved by high schoolers in that case, lol.

Comment: @WillJagy Can't say I understand your analogy, but I guess you might be hinting that there is an approach to finding the value of $f(10^{10})$ that may not generalize to all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x)$ has your desired property, then $\frac{p(x)}{10^{10}}$ is a polynomial with leading coefficient $\frac{1}{10^{10}}$ that sends integers to integers.  It's a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial#Classification) that all polynomials that send integers to integers are $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of the polynomials
$$
p_k(x) = \binom{x}{k} = \frac{x(x-1) \cdots (x-k+1)}{k!}.
$$
In particular, in order to get any coefficient with a denominator of $10^{10}$ (or even a denominator divisible by $5^{10}$), we must use polynomials with degree $k$ large enough that $k!$ is divisible by $5^{10}$.  This requires $k \geq 45$, so your example (which happens to equal $45! p_{45}(x+44)$) is optimal.  The same approach generalizes to prove that for all $n$, $f(n)$ is the smallest $k$ such that $n | k!$.