# When two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_n [x]$ define the same function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we are considering polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_n [x]$. Is there a way to decide if two polynomials determine the same function from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to itself without having to plug in all numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

For example in  $\mathbb{Z}_3 [x]$, I know that the polynomials $x^4 +x$ and $x^2 + x$ define the same function from  $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to itself. Is there any way to prove this without plugging in all values in  $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Hint: Well, why not subtract them and see if it's constant zero? That'd be way easier...

Comment: The cases where $n$ is prime are easier to describe than for composite $n$.

Comment: If you subtract them and are able to factor it, check to see if all members of $\mathbb Z_3$ are zeros of that difference. In your case, you have $x^4-x^2=x^2(x-1)(x+1)=(x-0)^2(x-1)(x-2)$ and all elements of  $\mathbb Z_3$ are zeros.

Comment: Note that for $p$ prime any two polynomials in degree at most $p-1$ are distinct as functions and any polynomial in degree $p$ or higher can be reduced to one like that by using $x^p-x=0$ so one can do the reduction and check coefficients  eg for $p=3$ obviously $x^4$ reduces to $x^2$ so the op claim is immediate

Comment: This link pretty much shows why this question is not trivial: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070051/how-many-distinct-polynomials-are-there-mod-n/4070413#4070413

Comment: Closely related to  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387540/polynomials-that-induce-the-zero-function-mod-n

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386902/finding-equivalent-polynomials-mod-n/4071007#4071007) of mine; as far as I can tell the question is the same?