# Proving a number is a carmichael number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prove $n$ is a Carmichael number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83358/how-do-i-prove-n-is-a-carmichael-number)

I am trying to verify the fact that $1729$ is a Carmichael number. However, a number $n$ is a carmichael number if and only if $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for all $a$ that are relatively prime to $n$. Is there any more efficient way of showing that it is a carmichael number short of testing all of the numbers that are relatively prime to $1729$?

Comment: Not quite, that post qualifies the nature of a general carmichael number, while this seeks to show that the characteristics presented in the other post hold in the case of 1729.

Comment: I agree they are not identical, but doesn't the general question subsume the specific one?  It immediately shows that there is a more efficient way to verify Carmichaelness, which was your question.