# Show that $(1,2, ...,n)$ has at most $\varphi(n)/2$ of $\varphi(n)$-course numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Given is the number $n$ which is divisible by the square of a prime number $p$.
Let a positive integer $a$ be euler-course when $n\mid (a^n -a)/a$.
Show that $(1,2, ...,n)$ has at most $\varphi(n)/2$ of  $\varphi(n)$-course numbers.

I was trying to solve this using primitive roots, by looking at the primitive root of $p^2$, but I couldn't quite do it.

Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is "euler(n)"?

Comment: @qfwfq I meant euler's totient function for $n$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $n | (a^n-a)/a=a^{n-1}-a \implies ord(a) | n-1$.

Also, $ord(a) | \lambda(n)$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function?oldformat=true).

So, $ord(a) | \gcd(\lambda(n),n-1)=d$ (say).

Now, since $n$ is not square-free, $\lambda(n) \not | n-1$, [as proven here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157215/274536).

Hence, $d$ is a proper divisor of $\lambda(n)$, so $d < \lambda(n)$.

Now, $a$ is a root of $x^d-1$, and the roots of $x^d-1$ form a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n ^ \times$. The subgroup is proper, since $d < \lambda(n)$, S (say). So, $|S| \leq \lambda(n)/2 \leq \phi(n)/2$ i.e. the maximum possible number of such $a$'s is $\phi(n)/2$.