# Show that $a^6-1$ is divisible by $168$ whenever $(a,42)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been running into this type of problem a lot:

> Show that $a^6-1$ is divisible by $168$ whenever $(a,42)=1$.

First of all, by Euler's theorem, we have that
$$a^{\phi(42)}\equiv a^{12}\equiv1\pmod{42}.$$
Notice that
$$a^6a^6\equiv1\pmod{42}\text{ and }168=4\cdot42.$$
It follows that
$$a^{12}\equiv1\pmod{168},$$
$$a^{12}-a^6\equiv1-a^6\pmod{168},$$
$$a^6(a^6-1)\equiv1-a^6\pmod{168},$$
$$a^6-1\equiv a^6(1-a^6)\pmod{168},$$
$$a^6-1\equiv a^6-a^{12}\pmod{168}.$$
I get stuck here: How can I show that the RHS is congruent to zero modulo $168$?

Comment: I haven't learned anything like it, but it'd seem as though $a^n\equiv1\pmod{m}$ whenever $n|\phi(m)$.

Comment: Your last line is the same as your second line, which is the same as your first line. In other words, you haven't actually changed anything yet.

Comment: I'm just trying to make it very explicit that $a^6-1\equiv0\pmod{168}$.

Comment: That's [Carmichael's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Carmichael.27s_theorem): $a^{\lambda(168)}\equiv1\pmod{168}$ and $\lambda(168)=6$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By Fermat's Theorem, $a^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  Also by Fermat's Theorem, or otherwise, $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  Thus $a^6\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  So far, we have that 
$$a^6\equiv 1 \pmod {21}.$$
But $a$ is odd, so $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod 8$. It follows that 
$$a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {8}.$$
Now it's over.

Comment: I was just typing this up!

Comment: I can delete, if a more student-friendly solution appears.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Either apply [Carmichael's generalization of Euler-Fermat,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1726/242) or proceed directly via

$$\rm A^{N_j}\equiv 1\ \ (mod\ M_j)\ \Rightarrow\ A^{lcm\ N_j}\equiv 1\ \ (mod\ lcm\ M_j)$$

for $\rm \begin{cases}\rm \:N = (2,2,6)\\ \rm M = (8,3,7)\end{cases}\, $ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242). That's what Andre does. It's worth emphasis it's *general* form.