# Prove that $ n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by 6 for all $n\in \textbf{N}$

Tags: induction

Prove that $ n^3 + 5n  $ is divisible by 6 for all $ n \in \textbf{N} $.  I provide my proof below.

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: Note you can post the answers for your question in the above post, no need to post them separately. @BillDubuque, OP's asking for verification of his answer.

Comment: Proof verification or alternative proofs, potentially; but by answering it myself I add to the cache of problems/resources on this site irregardless of whether anyone else participates.  I presume this is why they provide you with the option to simultaneously post and answer a question, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: @Dargatz This problem (and minor variants) have been posted on MSE so many times now that I doubt there is little more novel anyone can say on it. In any case, if you are looking for verification or alternate proofs then you should explicitly state that in the question.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove 24 divides $u^3-u$ for all odd natural numbers $u$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233094/prove-24-divides-u3-u-for-all-odd-natural-numbers-u) and [If $n = m^3 - m$ for some integer $m$, then $n$ is a multiple of $6$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171719/if-n-m3-m-for-some-integer-m-then-n-is-a-multiple-of-6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$n^3+5n=n(n^2+5)$. One is odd and the other is even so 2 divides it.

$n^3+5n=n(n^2+5)\equiv n(n^2+2)\bmod 3$, so:

- if $n\equiv0 \bmod 3$ then $3$ divides it.
- if $n\equiv1$ or $-1 \bmod 3$, then $n^2\equiv1 \bmod 3$, so $3|n^2+2$.

$2$ and $3$ divide it, so $6$ divides it.

Comment: You can write $n^3+5n\equiv n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)\pmod 6$ to make your proof simpler.

Answer (score 7):

We prove that $ n^3 + 5n  $ is divisible by 6 for all $ n \in \textbf{N} $.

Base case:  Observe that if $ n = 1 $, then $ n^3 + 5n = 1 + 5 = 6 $.

So the base case holds.

Inductive step:  Assume that $ k^3 + 5k $ is divisible by 6 for some $ k\in\textbf{N} $.

We show that $ (k+1)^3 + 5(k+1) $ is divisible by 6.

Since 6 divides $ k^3 + 5k $, it follows that $ k^3 + 5k = 6q $ for some integer $ q $.

Obverse that

$ (k+1)^3 + 5(k+1) = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 + 5k + 5 = k^3 + 3k^2 + 8k+ 6 $

$ = 6(q+1) + 3k^2 + 3k  $.

We break this up into 2 cases to consider odd and even values of $ k $:

Case 1.  Suppose $ k $ is even.  Then $ k=2w $ for some integer $ w $.  Thus

$ 6(q+1) + 3k^2 + 3k =6(q+1) + 3(4w^2)+3(2w) = 6(q+1) + 6(2w^2) + 6w $

$ = 6(q+2w^2+w+1) $.

Case 2.  Consider $ k$ is odd.  Then $ k =2v + 1 $ for some integer $ v $.  Then

$ 6(q+1) + 3k^2 + 3k = 6(q+1) + 3(2v+1)^2 + 3(2v+1) $

$ = 6(q+1) + 3(4v^2+4v+1) + 6v+3 = 6(q+1) + 6(2v^2+2v)+6(v+1)$

$ = 6 (2v^2+3v+2+q) $.

So the claim holds for all $ n \in \textbf{N} $.

Comment: Correct, but too lengthy. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\displaystyle \ \ n^3\!+5n = n^3\!-\!n+6n = (n\!+\!1)n(n\!-\!1) + 6n = \color{#c00}6{ {n\!+\!1\choose 3}} + \color{#c00}6n\ $ is divisible by $\,\color{#c00}6$

[Alternatively](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860502/242) show $\,(n\!+\!1)n(n\!-\!1)\,$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$. Generally a sequence of $\,k\,$ consecutive integers contains a multiple of $\,k\,$ (pigeonholes being remainders mod $\,k).$

More generally $\ 2p\mid n^p-n\ $ for odd primes $p,\,$ since $\ p\mid n^p-n\ $ by [little Fermat,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) and it's divisible by $2$ since $\,n^p$ and $\,n\,$ have equal parity. Even more generally

**Theorem** $ $ [(Korselt's Pseudoprime Criterion)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) $\ $ For  $\rm\:1 < e,m\in \Bbb N\:$ we have
$$\rm \forall\, n\in\Bbb Z\!:\ m\mid n^e\!-n\ \iff\  m\ \ is\ \  squarefree,\ \  and \ \ p\!-\!1\mid e\!-\!1\ \, for\  all \ primes\ \ p\mid m$$

For a proof see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340267/242) Your case is $\,\rm\,e,m = 3,6\,$ and, indeed, $2\!-\!1,\,3\!-\!1\mid 3\!-\!1.$

Answer (score 3):

All numbers are either even or odd. So if n is odd, $2|n^3+5n$ as $n^3$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by 2 and $5n$ leaves remainder $1$. For even 'n' the case is trivial.

And all numbers can classified in $3k,3k+1,3k+2$ forms. So n=3k+1, the remainder of $n^3$ when divided by 3 is 1 and for $5n$ it will be $2$ and $2+1=3$.

And for $n=3k+2$, the $n^3$ leaves remainder 2 when divided by 3 and $5n$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by 3, hence proved. The case is trivial for n=3k.

Thus as the number $n^3+5n$ is always divisible by 2 & 3. thus it is always divisible by 6.